# What does this line of the code do?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I am a newbie to python. I am solving a problem on Hackerrank https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/maximize-it/problem.

I wasn't able to solve the problem so I had opened the discussions. I found a code there -

```
from itertools import product

K,M = map(int,input().split())
N = (list(map(int, input().split()))[1:] for _ in range(K))
results = map(lambda x: sum(i**2 for i in x)%M, product(*N))
print(max(results))
```

I have 2 doubts:

1. First, if I try to print N, it throws "generator object is not subscriptable" error, but the value is already converted into list, so I am unable to understand the reason for error.
2. I am unable to understand what will be stored as a result of `results=map(lambda x: sum(i**2 for i in x)%M, product(*N))`.

I understand what `product(*N)` does. But what would be the output of `sum(i**2 for i in x)%M`? Is it adding the squares of the values of list and then performing the modulus operation? Or is it something else?

Comment: "but the value is already converted into list" No it's not. N is a generator.

Comment: I can understand that from the error. But why is it so?

Comment: The use of the `()` brackets instead of the `[]` brackets.  `[]` indicate `list` which is stored in memory.  `()` indicate a generator which produces each value on the fly.

Answer (score 0):

#### For your 1st doubt:

**Why is N a generator?**

The `list` function is being applied to the `map(int, input().split())` statement and indeed that is a list being returned, however, the outermost pair of parentheses and `for _ in range(K)` means that a generator object is being returned to `N` and not the list. If you want to see the contents of N while debugging, change the outermost parentheses to square brackets `[` and `]` and add a `print(N)` statement after that as such:

```py
# Debug & view contents of N like this:
N = [ list(map(int, input().split()))[1:] for _ in range(K) ]
print(N)
```

#### For your 2nd doubt:

**How does the value of the variable `results` come about?**

Just so everyone who's reading this answer is clear, in the below example, I'll let:

`N = [[1, 2], [3, 4], [5, 6]]`

`product(*N)` will return an iterator for a list of tuples containing the cartesian product of each of the sublists of N, e.g. `product(*N)` returns the tuples `(1, 3, 5), (1, 3, 6), (1, 4, 5), (1, 4, 6), ..., (2, 4, 6)`.

You can verify this by doing `print([x for x in product(*N)])` or if you iterate through `N` in a for loop and print out each value as such:

```py
N = [[1, 2], [3, 4], [5, 6]]

# You can verify the contents of a generator like this:
print([item for item in product(*N)])

# Or like this:
for item in product(*N):
    print(item)
```

**Breaking down `results = map(lambda x: sum(i**2 for i in x)%M, product(*N))`**:

In `(i**2 for i in x)`, `x` refers to one of the tuples, e.g. `(1, 3, 5)` in `product(*N)`, and returns a generator that contains the values `(1, 9, 25)`. So it's basically squaring every integer in the tuple `(1, 3, 5)` and returning a tuple of their squares.

`sum(i**2 for i in x)` sums every integer in the tuple `x` to give you 1 + 9 + 25 = 35.

After that, the resultant sum, 35, is applied to the modulus operation `% M`.

Finally, `results` would contain the generator with all of the resultant modulus sums for every tuple. Similarly, you can verify the content of `results` by doing `print([x for x in results])` or if you iterate `results` in a for loop and print out each value just like how it's done in the code snippet above.

`print(max(results))` would then give you the largest value in `results`.

(*I assume Python-3.x is used.*)